# can't install windows 8.1 after erasing hard disk and installing Ubuntu!

Tags: 16.04

I am new in Ubuntu, I am totally unknown about the installation system of Ubuntu. I am using 493GB containing laptop. Previously I had Windows 7 then i installed Ubuntu by erasing the hard drive.

Now again I want to install windows and this time 8.1 but it can't find and hard drive to be installed as Ubuntu is grabbing all my space.

Please help me with any compatible suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

What might make sense here is to start with creating an Ubuntu live CD (or USB stick), and booting to that. When you have booted, use GParted to view the disk and determine what is on there i.e. is it one large Ubuntu partition or something else.

As long as you have enough free space to be able to shrink down, you should shrink down the partition(s) to create enough room for a Windows installation - I would suggest at least 100GB, but probably more. Then you will need to move the Linux partition(s) to the end of the drive, as Windows is fussy about where it is installed and it's better to place it right at the start of the hard drive space.

Do you have UEFI or BIOS? That will make a difference to how Windows installs too - you should know if you have installed Linux in EFI mode or Legacy mode, as you shouldn't mix the two.

Once you have done this, boot the Windows installation media and hopefully the installer will find adequate space to install. You'll probably find that you can't boot to GRUB anymore, so once Windows is installed, you will need to repair GRUB to boot both operating systems. Check this out for instructions:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Once you have GRUB repaired, you should be able to boot to either OS from the GRUB menu.